# Center div and fit contents?

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div in the middle of my page, and have the div fit the contents. How can I do that?

---

I've tried

```
width: 1px;
white-space: nowrap;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Which centers the div, but then all the text is to the right of that.

`display: inline-block` makes the div fit the contents, but then `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Well, if you make it `inline-block` then you have to set `text-align:center` on it's parent to center it...

Comment: @Sime: Should have posted this as an answer....I'd give you the checkmark. Edit: Oh..you did ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does this work for you: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/inline-centered-div.html

```
body { text-align:center; }
div { display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: That makes everything on the page centered.

Comment: @Blindy It's just a demo. On the page, the OP has to define text-align:center on the DIV's parent element (which wont be the BODY element in his case).

Comment: Yes, yes it does. Although I'm going to wrap it in an extra div and put the `text-align:center` on that instead, and then I just have to put `text-align:left` on the inner div.

Comment: @Ralph Yea, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, if you want to center some text, you would make use of a container that spans the container in which you are centering and set `text-align: center;`.

CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:
    
        my text

If you want a container that's sized around the text, for purposes of a color background or border, stick in another inner container.

CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}

#inner_div {
    display: inline;
    /*other styles here*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner_div">my text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

So you have two options. If you don't *actually* need the div to fit the contents and just want the content centered without having to specify a width for the div, you can simply do:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <input type="button" value="Example Button" />
</div>
```

However, if you actually *do* want a div around your contents, such as to make a nice looking border or something, you can simply use two divs, instead:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <input type="button" value="Example Button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer div will fill the space of the parent, the inner div will wrap its contents (which is a button, in this instance), and the button and inner div will be centered.

Answer (score 1):

Try `display: table;`

```
div { 
    display: table; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox should do the trick:

```
.container {
        display: flex;
}

.centeredDiv {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is to the right because of width:1px. Set a bigger width.

Comment: ...yes, I understand *why*, but "set a bigger width" doesn't meet the "fit contents" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, javascript solutions aside, is to give it a width and set its left and right margins to auto:

```
<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width=80%">...</div>
```

All the other solutions will mess up your inner text.

Comment: I want to fit the contents, not a % width.